# How to smoothly rerender expensive component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I need your help here ! And hello guys

I'm building an app in ReactNative, I have a SectionList that renders quite expensive/heavy elements. There is not so much items in the list (between 20 & 30), for the moment.

The thing is, I need the data list to be filterable/groupable. When the list is filtered or grouped, the SectionList rerender (well it's expected), but the whole UI freezes for 2/3s.

The items of the SectionList are already memoized (React.memo), but they do rerender anyway.

The whole filtering/grouping is done in a redux selector (the data comes from the store too).

```
        <SectionList
          sections={internalOrders}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <OrderItem order={item} navigation={navigation}></OrderItem>}
          renderSectionHeader={({ section: { name } }) => (
            <Text fontSize="sm" color="grey" py="2" px="4" bg="lightgrey">
              {name}
            </Text>
          )}
        ></SectionList>
```

Is there any way to optimize more ? Is it possible to show a spinner while it's rendering ?

Comment: Have you tried switching from passing desired functions as props to a named children pattern? Sometimes I find this helps me.

Comment: the code of the section list seems fine to me! can it be the filtering logic in redux doing the freeze causing?

Comment: It may be caused by item or navigation but it's declaration is not in the posted code.

Comment: @RizwanAtta
Actually, it's the OrderItem that causes the freeze, because it's a quite heavy component. Replacing it by a simple Text removes the freeze. 
So the big question is : how to render heavy components without freezing the app ?
And about the SectionList : it's seems to rerenders all the items anyway. Is it not supposed to renders on screens items only ?

Comment: can you try manipulating data using data and newData props? @holyris

Comment: @RizwanAtta I don't understand, manipulating data in which way ? what are data & newData props ?

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist#extradata
see this please @holyris

Comment: @RizwanAtta extradata is used to tell the SectionList to rerender, actually I dont need to do that. The sectionList already rerenders when I need.

Comment: @holyris can you show a little gif or video of the issue or maybe can share a JS Fiddle to test on expo to recreate the issue or GitHub repo! so we can test and see the issue. Thanks